# Repeat values in every 14th row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am creating a csv to import it to my database.

I want to repeat values in every 14th row of the column in excel.

[image]

You can see the screenshot of what I want to achieve. There are about 10k records, so I can't copy paste the sequence number..

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: larger image here http://prntscr.com/53awce

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first number always starts in cell C2, enter this in C3 and copy down:

```
=MOD(ROW()-2,14)+$C$2
```

Answer (score 0):

'This will work upto 1000 cells

'Create a code module and paste it

'Then run macro

'Assumed that this is first sheet

Sub Macro()

i as Integer

j as Integer

i=14

For j=2 to 1000

i=i+1

If i=29 then

i=15

Endif

Sheet1.Cells(j,3).Value=i

Next j

End Sub()